# Problem with default value in dataGridview column when adding a new row

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a form (**form1**) with a dataGridView listing customer orders from a table called "**Orders**". When an order is selected in the dataGridView and the EnterKey is pressed, another form (**form2**) pops-up. This popup form2 has another dataGridView that supports adding rows where the user enters a new record related to the selected order into a table called "**OrderDetails**" which has a foreigh key column called OrderNumber which refers to the OrderNumber column in table "Orders".

**Problem:**

when the user is entering a new record from the dataGridView on form2 into the orderDetails table, i want the OrderNumber column to be populated automatically. Its value should be the order number value of the selected record on form1 such that the user doesn't have to type it manually since its already known. Help.

The datagridview is bound to a bidningSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just got it working the way i wanted with

```
private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  e.Row.Cells["CustomerNumber"].Value = myOrderNumberValue;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an event on a BindingSource you can catch called 'AddingNew'. Here you can specify what the new object and its properties will be. Like this:

```
private void BindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    OrderDetailLIne odl = new OrderDetailLIne();
    odl.OrderNumber = _orderNumber;
    e.NewObject = odl;
}
```